# Move items fully left or right responsive CSS

Tags: html, css

So I know a LIL bit about html/css and I made this navbar

[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEryb.png)

As you an see logo and burger menu are not responsive with big screens

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    box-sizing: inherit!important;
}
html{
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif!important;
    font-size: 10px!important;
    box-sizing: border-box!important;
}
header{
    background-color: #ff0000!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}
.nav-container{
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: 1200px!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    padding: 0 10px!important;
}
nav{
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 85px!important;
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    justify-content: space-between!important;
}
.nav-brand{
    width: 60px!important;
    height: 60px!important;
    display: flex!important;
    z-index: -1!important;
}
.nav-brand ion-icon{
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 40px!important;
}
.nav-list{
    display: flex!important;
    list-style: none!important;
}
.nav-link{
    display: block!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    padding: 0 30px!important;
    font-size: 20px!important;
    transform: scale(0)!important;
    transition: transform 650ms!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
.nav-item{
    position: relative!important;
    line-height: 85px!important;
    transition-delay: .7s!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
.nav-item::before{
    content: ""!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 5px!important;
    background-color: white!important;
    left: 0!important;
    bottom: 0!important;
    transform: scaleX(0)!important;
    transform-origin: right!important;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
.nav-item:hover::before{
    transform: scaleX(1)!important;
    transform-origin: left!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

/* ------------------Hamburguer Menu------------------- */

.hamburguer{
    width: 40px!important;
    height: 40px!important;
    position: relative!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    z-index: 1500!important;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.line1{
    height: 5px!important;
    width: 40px!important;
    background-color: #fff!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    display: block!important; 
    right: 0!important;
    transition: all 650ms!important;
}
.line1:nth-child(1){
    top: 0!important;
}
.line1:nth-child(2){
    top: 50%!important;
    width: 30px!important;
    margin-top: -6px!important;
}
.line1:nth-child(3){
    top: 100%!important;
    width: 20px!important;
    margin-top: -11px!important;
}
.hamburguer.active .line1:nth-child(1){
    top: 20%!important;
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg)!important;
    width: 40px!important;
    margin-top: 0!important;
}
.hamburguer.active .line1:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0!important;
}
.hamburguer.active .line1:nth-child(3){
    top:70%!important;
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg)!important;
    width: 40px!important;
    margin-top: 0!important;
}

/* ----------menu oculto---------- */
.nav-list.active .nav-link{
    transform: scale(1)!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item{
    transition-delay: initial!important;
    visibility: visible!important;
    color: #fff!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item:nth-child(1) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .5s!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item:nth-child(2) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .4s!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item:nth-child(3) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .3s!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item:nth-child(4) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .2s!important;
}
.nav-list.active .nav-item:nth-child(5) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .1s!important;
}
/* ---------Reverse Delay----------------*/
.nav-item:nth-child(1) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .1s!important;
}
.nav-item:nth-child(2) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .2s!important;
}
.nav-item:nth-child(3) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .3s!important;
}
.nav-item:nth-child(4) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .4s!important;
}
.nav-item:nth-child(5) .nav-link{
    transition-delay: .5s!important;
}

/*-------------Responsive entre 0 y 500 pixeles-------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .nav-list{
        width: 100%!important;
        flex-direction: column!important;
        align-items: center!important;
        justify-content: center!important;
        background-color: #ff0000!important;
        position: fixed!important;
        left: 0!important;
        bottom: -100vh!important;
        transition: 650ms!important;
        height: 100vh!important;
        z-index: 289!important;
    }
    .nav-list.active{
        bottom: 0px!important;
    }


}
```

This is all css for navbar.
Do anyone know how to make them to stick to left or right even on big screens?
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎Like i tried float left right and all but ig something is blocking it?

Comment: max-width: 1200px!important; ?!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `max-width:1200px!important` seems to be the problem, it set the max width to 1200px, so you can't have a full-width nav on scrreen greater than 1200px.

**NOTE:** Avoid using `!important` everywhere

```css
.nav-container{
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: 1200px!important; /*This line is the problem */
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    padding: 0 10px!important;
}
```

You're .nav-container css should look like that:

```css
.nav-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```